# Error in Peoplcode ScrollSelect processing

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

When I'm trying to open the page I get the error that "Return: 8011 - SQL statment is too long". We have about millions of rows.

On the page we are filling the scroll and the where statement is created something like this

```
For &i = 1 To &rs.ActiveRowCount

&PARAM1 = &rs(&i).Record.SETID.Value;

&PARAM2 = &rs(&i).Record.VENDOR_ID.Value;

&strWhere = &strWhere | " OR ";

&strWhere = &strWhere | "(SETID = " | "'" |(&PARAM1) | "'" | " AND VENDOR_ID = " | "'" |(&PARAM2) | "'" | ")";

End-for;
```

Is there a limit while doing a Scroll select?

Comment: I could be wrong, but that looks like a database error message. What database are you using?

Comment: Does your statement about "millions of rows" mean that you have millions of criteria in your where clause?

Comment: The error is that your SQL STATEMENT is too long, not that the limit for querying has been reached. You shouldnt do an OR like this. You can try an IN statement to save you some characters.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the SQL that populated &rs.
2. Modify your SQL that uses &strWhere that it joins to the &rs record, which is filtered the same as you populated &rs.

It's a little tricky to explain because you'll need to change more than just your code snippet.

Modify your code so it does something more like this:

```
&strWhere = ", PS_SOME_RECORD b where b.keyfield_1 = :1 and b.keyfield_2 = :2 ";
&strWhere = &strWhere | "and b.setid = a.setid ";
&strWhere = &strWhere | "and b.vendorid = a.vendorid";
```

Same same but different:

```
&strWhere = " inner join PS_SOME_RECORD b on b.setid = a.setid and b.vendor_id = a.vendor_id ";
&strWhere = &strWhere | "and b.keyfield_1 = :1 and b.keyfield_2 = :2";
```

Basically: use the database instead of trying to build up a 1,000,000 line SQL statement.

Ultimately you want to return from the database (assuming VENDOR table) something not unlike:

```
select *
from ps_vendor a
    inner join ps_your_rs_table b 
    on b.setid = a.setid 
    and b.vendor_id = a.vendor_id
where b.some_field = [your filter/predicates]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is due to the length of the value passed in where condition "IN".

Since the data value passed in IN ("") exceeds the limit, hence it results in this error.